# How to make a control in android like following?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have tried using FrameLayout but it doesnt solve my problem.
I want this control to be adaptable to different texts and different images. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a 9 patch image as the background of a `Button` or `ImageButton`. Read more on 9 patches:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html